# Impossible to disable click on datepicker

Tags: android, kotlin, datepicker

I would like to disable the click on a datepicker in my layout but I can't find the attribute to edit to disable the click. 
I tried to set clickable to false, focusable to false but nothing seems to work. I can always click on it and set a date.

I have an event on my fab button that enable and disable my edittext and checkedit and it's working perfectly.
I just can't get to disable the datepicker

Here is the xml of my activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    tools:context=".ui.detail.DetailFoodActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/detailFoodName"
        style="@style/Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailTextDate"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/detailFoodName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailFoodName" />

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/detailDatePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:datePickerMode="calendar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailTextDate" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/action_edit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit_white_24dp" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/detailDatePicker">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonEaten"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="Eaten" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButtonBin"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:text="At the bin" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/detailTextViewName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:lineSpacingExtra="0dp"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textAlignment="viewStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        android:typeface="serif"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

If anyone knows how to disable it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can enable/disable it by using setEnabled() properties of DatePicker Control

```
setEnabled(true)
setEnabled(false)
```

Here's [a link of android document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker) for more reference

Comment: it is not working it only disable the title but I can still click and change the date

Comment: if you want you can use another option for the same. User EditText and open DatePicker Dialog on it Click Event.